# How do I get the external IP of a socket in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

When I call `socket.getsockname()` on a socket object, it returns a tuple of my machine's internal IP and the port. However, I would like to retrieve my external IP. What's the cheapest, most efficient manner of doing this?

Comment: Another great website that offers a no frills solution is to get an HTTP request from [icanhazip.com](http://icanhazip.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible without cooperation from an external server, because there could be any number of NATs between you and the other computer. If it's a custom protocol, you could ask the other system to report what address it's connected to.

Answer (score 7):

The only way I can think of that's guaranteed to give it to you is to hit a service like http://whatismyip.com/ to get it.

Comment: Not quite sure why this was voted down.  This is IMHO the only way to get the external IP address of any system.  Just because a router tells you what it thinks your IP address is, or what it thinks it's IP address is doesn't mean there isn't another NAT in place.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel: +1 for mentioning another NAT. Also, different external services may see different external IPs e.g.,  I remember that to access a library site, I had to use a different route so that the site sees different (allowed) ip i.e., the public ip may depend on destination.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/bobeirasa/mini-scripts/blob/master/externalip.py

```
'''
Finds your external IP address
'''

import urllib
import re

def get_ip():
    group = re.compile(u'(?P<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)').search(urllib.URLopener().open('http://jsonip.com/').read()).groupdict()
    return group['ip']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_ip()
```

Comment: Was not aware of jsonip.com--thanks.  Here's a little more "jsonic" variation of your answer (auto formatting is messing up the url):     json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('http://jsonip.com/', headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})).read())['ip']

Comment: @Rafael Lopes The link was moved to `https://jsonip.com/` (301 permanently). Btw. for me it works perfectly. In my case, the external IP in the response is in IPv6 format, which is fine. Nice one.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use an external system to do this.

DuckDuckGo's IP answer will give you exactly what you want, and in JSON!

```
import requests

def detect_public_ip():
    try:
        # Use a get request for api.duckduckgo.com
        raw = requests.get('https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=ip&format=json')
        # load the request as json, look for Answer.
        # split on spaces, find the 5th index ( as it starts at 0 ), which is the IP address
        answer = raw.json()["Answer"].split()[4]
    # if there are any connection issues, error out
    except Exception as e:
        return 'Error: {0}'.format(e)
    # otherwise, return answer
    else:
        return answer

public_ip = detect_public_ip()
print(public_ip)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most simple method of getting a public IP is by using this

```
import requests

IP = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org/').text
print(f'Your IP is: {IP}')
```

Answer (score 2):

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("msn.com",80))

s.getsockname()

Answer (score 1):

```
print (urllib.urlopen('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp').read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the address suggested in the source of http://whatismyip.com

```
import urllib
def get_my_ip_address():
    whatismyip = 'http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp'
    return urllib.urlopen(whatismyip).readlines()[0]
```

Comment: note they say to not do this more than once every 300 seconds

Answer (score 0):

---

You need to make connection to an external Server And Get Your Public IP From The Response

---

**like this**:

```
   import requests

   myPublic_IP = requests.get("http://wtfismyip.com/text").text.strip()

   print("\n[+] My Public IP: "+ myPublic_IP+"\n")
```